# The viewport doesn't work in direct3d 10

Tags: viewport

I set my viewport as following

```
D3D10_VIEWPORT vp;

vp.TopLeftX = 0;
vp.TopLeftY = 0;
vp.Width    = 320;   
vp.Height   = 320;
vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

mDevice -> RSSetViewports(1, &vp);
```

But the problem is whether I use viewport or not, I can render onto the window. And chaning vp.Width or vp.Height doesn't get any effect. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't specify viewport in your program, DirectX will create a one for you, its' size is the client size of your rendering window.